When using pydicom to read an RGB DICOM image, does it automatically convert it to the format (x, y, channel)?
When using pydicom to read an RGB DICOM image, does it automatically convert it to the format (x, y, channel)? This is because my Planar Configuration is 1, but the size of pixel_data is (301, 301, 3).
I want to convert my RGB DICOM to a binary image, but I find I'm not familiar with DICOM or pydicom.

If you're converting to a NumPy ndarray, then yes, the shape will be (Rows, Columns, Number of Samples) for single-frame multi-sample Pixel Data. If you have multiple frames the shape will be (Number of Frames, Rows, Columns, Number of Samples).
